# Помогите пожайлуста с решением ошибки-'boards.lists' is of type 'unknown'. Ошибка появляеться в jsx коде

Tags: reactjs, html5, typescript, axios

```typescript
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../../stylesBoard/board.css';
import List from './List';
import api from '../../api/request';
import dragOnDrop from './dragOnDrop';

function Board() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Моя тестова дошка");

  const [boards, setBoards] = useState({});
  const [listCreate, setListCreate] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(1);
  const [createListCounter, setCreateListCounter] = useState(0);
  function handleCreateList() {
    if (createListCounter === 1) {
      postResponse();
    } else {
      setListCreate(true);
      setCreateListCounter(createListCounter + 1);
    }
  }
  function handleInputChange(event:any) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  }
  const id = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
  async function postResponse() {
    try {
      if(inputValue.trim()!==""){
        await api.post(`https://trello-back.shpp.me/maliiev/api/v1/board/${id}/list`, {
          title: inputValue,
          position:2
        });
        setListCreate(false);
        setInputValue("");
        setCreateListCounter(0);
    }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Ошибка при добавлении списка:", error);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getResponse() {
      const data=await api.get(`https://trello-back.shpp.me/maliiev/api/v1/board/${id}`);
      setBoards(data);
     }
     getResponse();
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="Board">
      <div className='container'>
        <header className='Board__header'>
          <button className="Board__header-btn btn" type="submit">&#8592; домой</button>
          <p className='Board__header-title'>{title}</p>
          <div className='Board__header-block'></div>
        </header>
        <section className='Board__section'>
        {"lists" in boards?(
            boards.lists.map((item:any)=>{
              return <List title={item.title} cards={item.cards}/>
            })
          ):(
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )
        }
          <div className='Board__list' draggable="true">
            <input className="Board__section-btn" type='submit' value="+ Додати список" onClick={handleCreateList} />
            {listCreate && <input type="text" value={inputValue} onChange={handleInputChange} />}
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Board;
```

Comment: Где именно в вашем коде вы эту ошибку получаете?

Comment: в jsx коде. boards.lists

Comment: `"lists" in boards` ---  а что это за конструкция? Она легальная?

Comment: А что непонятного в ошибке? У вас `boards` `unknown` и логично почему.

Comment: Я реально немогу понять что нетак и как это пофиксить

Comment: Вначале ответь на вопрос: `"lists" in boards` - это корректная конструкция? И где о таком написано.

Comment: С помощью этой строки я проверяю есть ли масив lists в обьекте boards. Узнал я о таком способе благодаря chatGPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка происходит потому что вы не указали тип переменной `boards`

Вот как можно это исправить:

```typescript
interface IBoards {
  lists?: any // тут тип листа
}

function Board() {
  // ...
  const [boards, setBoards] = useState<IBoards>({});
  // ...
```